# Unable to open .gxw file in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass

I am unable to open associate *.gxw files with grass gis 7.8.2 executable. I am using windows 8.1. Below I am attaching the error I have received.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtvdo.png)